# Proving inequality with $e$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $$s_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}$$ and define $e = \lim_{n \to \infty} s_n$. I have already shown that this limit exists (by comparison with a geometric series), and am now asked to show that, for all $n \geq 1$, $$e-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!} < \frac{1}{n!\,n}$$

I was able to show this with $\leq$, but couldn't see how to show it with the required strict $<$, since limits preserve weak inequalities but in general don't preserve strict inequalities. So any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$ \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac {n!} {k!} <\frac 1 {n+1}+\frac 1 {(n+1)^{2}}+\frac 1 {(n+1)^{3}}+\cdots=\frac {1/(n+1)} {1-1/(n+1)}=\frac  1 n$. Now divide by $n!$.

You have to separate the term with $k=n+2$ from the remaining infinite sum to see why you have strict in equality.

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I did, but why are you allowed to write $<$ rather than $\leq$?

Comment: Because $(n+1)(n+2) >(n+1)^{2}$. For the remaining terms you get $\leq $ and for this term you get $<$. So for the  sum you get strict inequality.  @Prasiortle

Comment: But $(n+1)(n+2) > (n+1)^2$, or $\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} < \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$, doesn't mean that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} < \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$. Just as, for example, $\frac{1}{n+1} < \frac{1}{n}$ doesn't mean that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n+1} < \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: @Prasiortle Suppose $a_1 <b_1$ and $a _i \leq b_i$ for $i \geq 2$. Then $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i <\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} b_i$.

Comment: Why is that true?

Comment: Because $a<b$ and $c \leq d$ implies $a+c<b+d$. @Prasiortle

Comment: @Prasiortle: Another way to look at it is $a_2+a_3+\cdots\leq b_2+b_2+\cdots$ and both of these sums are finite numbers. So we have something like $L\leq M$. If $a_1<b_1$, then $a_1+L<b_1+M$.

Comment: @Clayton I think I understand now based on your comment. Kabo Murphy, what you have written is correct for sums of two terms, but it is not clear that this applies to infinite sums.